# Varying DC pass only over set threshold (LM358)

Tags: operational-amplifier, voltage-monitor

First timer here (microcontroller hobbyist).

**I need to let voltage pass from battery to step down converter only when voltage exceeds set threshold.** There's some MCU stuff behind the 5V step down converter.

I'm new to op-amps and comparators, and this is what I got from the first iteration:

[image]

- Green line is voltage variations 12.5 - 14.5V simulating motorcycle battery voltage during idle and while being driven.
- Blue is voltage from potentiometer (adjusting the threshold).
- Red is Zener voltage reference.
- Cyan is the current over LOAD (1-1.5A is probable value on max draw on load).

**1) It's in a motorcycle, should I expect interference of some kind while driving?**

**2) Are there any major flaws in the circuit?** I know there probably are, but I'm yet in no position to catch them all.

**3) Should I make the circuit so that GND levels match**? Although that might be irrelevant, since the microcontroller stuff is in a closed box and aren't in any other connection to the motorcycle (seems that I really need to learn how to use PMOS).

**EDIT: D2 is mistakenly plain diode in schema, should be LED**

Comment: It mostly looks OK. (1) What are R2 and D2 for? (2) You could add some resistors above and below X1 so that you get finer control over more of the span of the pot - unless you're using a 10-turn pot. (3) I don't see any decoupling capacitor in U1. You'll need it on a motorbike with all sorts of noise from ignition, etc.

Comment: @Transistor Yeah, I played with the resistors and they were in my LM339 schema. Definitely something to add here since we want finer changes into voltage level. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand what R2, D2 is for.  They are just in parallel with the load.
If the entirety of what is connected at the *load* is not connected to the motorcycle electrical, then you can leave it as is.
But if you had a different type of load, or just want to know how to use a PMOS, see below.  The goal of the voltage divider R1, R2 is to apply \$ >V{_g}{_sth}\$ to M2 so that it is fully on.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFURFY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your answer. R2 and LED was just remnants of me testing the circuit. Would they be ok to leave as parallel as an indicator LED that the circuit is working, so one could quick adjust the threshold with potentiometer without load or multimeter?

I'll try to implement PMOS into another schema, I'll be back tomorrow. EDIT: Oops the LED has been switched to plain diode in some stage of the build :D

Comment: @sakabug D2 as an LED that makes much more sense! Yes, it would be fine like that, and makes a good visual indicator.